# Preventing Opera from switching over to new tab

Tags: browser, opera, browser-tabs

How do I prevent Opera from switching over to the tab I opened when I click on 'Open in new tab'? This feature of Opera is driving me nuts! Is there a setting or something that I can change so that the focus remains on the current tab?

Comment: What a shame. Practically every browser nowdays allows you to configure this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>Shift</kbd>`+ Click` on the link should open it in a background tab.

<strike>but the preference to not change focus to the new tab [should be under](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.50/en/tabs.html)

`Preferences > Advanced > Tabs`</strike>

**EDIT:** but Gnoupi says it isn't. **:(**

Comment: Actually, you would think that, but no, it's not. Check again your link, you can choose if the next tab will be maximized, or not, things like this, but you can't decide if switching or not.

Comment: the ctrl+shift option is working all right.

Comment: Or, instead of choosing "Open in new tab" you choose "Open in new background tab". No additional work. Just click one line further down.

Comment: jweede - Ctrl + Shift +Click does what I want it to do - pity I can't change it as the default setting. Thanks!

Comment: @StampedeXV : You should post it as an answer, as it's obviously the closest answer to his problem. It doesn't require to press keys, only to go lower in menu.

Comment: @Gnoupi - Keyboard Junkie here :D would rather choose to hit  Ctrl + Shift +Click rather than right click, move mouse and then choose Open in New Background

Comment: yea, but jweede could add it to his answer. It is more like an annotation, although a correct one :).

@Sathya: You'd really want to do this as the default? So every click on a link would open a new Window? I don't think so. Thats the reason, why you can't choose this as default I think, cause it really makes no sense. :)

Comment: @Stampede - You mean open new (background) tab - and its not for every link I click, but majority of them, and I would certainly make this as default.

Answer (score 13):

Don't click "Open in new tab". In Opera feature you want is called **"Open in Background Tab"**.

But IMHO best solution is to use middle mouse button click. In Preferences → Advanced → Shortcuts → Middle-Click options you can change how middle mouse button behaves (if it doesn't open in background already).

Comment: Middle click does a Flip-3D (not that I use Flip-3d anyways), but the open in background tab does what I need

Comment: Never heard of Flip3d. Is that some crapware bundled with mouse drivers? Just disable/remove it and get real middle mouse button working.

Comment: Flip-3d -> is the window switcher which comes with Win Vista / 7.

Comment: @Sathya: Change your settings on the Microsoft Mouse driver (assuming that's what you're using). It has this bad habit of rendering the middle-click useless by default.

Comment: @musicfreak - thanks, I have a Logitech wireless mouse, changed the settings in Set point and now its correctly configured!

Answer (score 3):

Just Middle-click on the link will open the link URL in a new background tab.
If this is not working for you, Then go to Preferences. Go to Advanced tab. Select Shoutcuts.
Click on "Middle Click Options" button. Here select "open in background tab" radio option. 
Hope this works for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find an option to prevent that.

The only thing that I can advise you for now, is to "middle-click" the links you want to open in a new tab, <strike>or use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click on a link</strike> (this one switches to the new tab, not matching, so).

I'm guessing that this is "by design". If you take the time to make a right click, then clicking on "Open in a New Tab", they assume that you want to switch to it. "Assuming" is always a dangerous thing, and often leads to such problems. Pity they haven't made it an option in preferences.

**Edit:** I check about:config, but I can't find such option either.

Comment: Middle click does a Flip-3D (not that I use Flip-3d anyways), but yeah with shift-click it switches over to the new tab.
But yes - pity they don't have the option.

Comment: You might be able to turn off the middle-click activating Flip-3D using the Mouse control panel. I've got mine set to 'middle click' and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you really are a "keyboard junkie", like you said in a comment, then you can do all this from keyboard !

- **Solution 1** (text only) : Press <kbd>/</kbd>, type a part of the link, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- **Solution 2** (all links) : Navigate to your link using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ a directional arrow (you can navigate the whole page in a directional way), then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: You mean navigate links using Shift + arrow keys! Ctrl+ keys goes forward/backward